# Quickfix - Tag not defined for this message type

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm getting an exec report from my counter party, and my quickfix engine is rejecting it for "Tag not defined for this message type 371=1300"

It seems to be saying that the exec report has a non-standard tag (1300), and my quickfix engine doesn't like it.

However, I have added that tag into my dictionary XML file, as follows

```
  <field number="1300" name="MarketSegmentID" type="String" added="FIX.5.0" addedEP="52" abbrName="MktSegID" textId="FIELD_1300">
    <enum value="BETP" symbolicName="BETP" textId="ENUM_1300_BETP"/>
    <enum value="BGL" symbolicName="BGL" textId="ENUM_1300_BGL"/>
    <enum value="BMTF" symbolicName="BMTF" textId="ENUM_1300_BMTF"/>
    <enum value="BSEF" symbolicName="BSEF" textId="ENUM_1300_BSEF"/>
  </field>
```

So it should know about tag 1300. My counter party sends "1300=BSEF", so it's one of the valid choices.

What exactly does "tag not defined for this message type" mean? What should I try?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two main sections to your XML file: (1) The message definitions, and (2) the tag definitions.

You added the tag definition, but you didn't edit the ExecutionReport message definition to include that new tag.