# QuickFix - Tag not defined for this message - Celer tech

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I've seen this questioned asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38600735/quickfix-tag-not-defined-for-this-message-type)
and have applied the suggested solution but am still coming up with

> Tag not defined for this message

I'm sending this message :

```
toapp : 8=FIX.4.4|9=151|35=V|34=2|49=Test|52=20180731-14:35:54.947|56=UAT-Test|55=EUR/USD|63=SP|115=Username|167=FOR|207=XCEL|262=1|263=1|264=0|265=0|461=SPOT|10=074|
```

and getting this back

```
toadmin : 8=FIX.4.4|9=134|35=3|34=3|49=Test|52=20180731-14:35:54.982|56=UAT-Test|45=2|58=Tag not defined for this message type|371=264|372=W|373=2|10=090|
```

The entry in the data dictionary for marketdatarequest is :

```
<message name="MarketDataRequest" msgtype="V" msgcat="app">
<field name="MDReqID" required="Y"/>
<field name="SubscriptionRequestType" required="Y"/>
<field name="MarketDepth" required="Y"/>
<field name="Symbol" required="Y"/>
<field name="SecurityType" required="Y"/>
<field name="MDUpdateType" required="Y"/>
<field name="CFICode" required="Y"/>
<field name="SettlType" required="Y"/>
<field name="OnBehalfOfCompID" required="N"/>
<field name="SecurityExchange" required="Y"/>
</message>

...

<field number="264" name="MarketDepth" type="INT"/>
```

All the other FIX implementations I've come across also have `NoMDEntryTypes` and `NoRelatedSym` groups which this does not which is strange but this is what the spec requires.

Also am I correct in saying that if I send an toapp message and get the toadmin message back with no fromapp/fromadmin message, does that mean quickfix intercepted the message as incorrectly formed and never sent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rejection is not for your market data request. I can tell this from tag `372=W` in the rejection:

> **FIX 4.4 : RefMsgType <372> field**
>
> The MsgType <35> (35) of the FIX message being referenced.

[Source](https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/tagNum_372.html)

MsgType W refers to a [market data snapshot](https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/msgType_W_87.html).

From the information you've given, I can infer that you send a MarketDataRequest (`35=V`) which presumably works successfully. The server you're connecting to replies with a snapshot (`35=W`) and your FIX engine then automatically responds to them with a rejection, because their snapshot includes tag 264 which are you not expecting.

Comment: ah this makes sense. I'm still having trouble working my way through the messages but this makes things a lot clearer. I've added the 264 tag to MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh in the data dictionary and it works perfectly. many thanks

Comment: @user3533333 can you mark this answer as accepted, so it doesn't show up on the list as still needing assistance?